# Error whe use where statement on flutter drift query

Tags: flutter, drift

It's been several hours and I couldn't find a solution. I have multiple queries working fine with flutter drift, but when I add a where statement I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of
> type '(HasResultSet) => Expression' of 'filter'

The query is:

```
Future<dynamic> getById(int id) async {
  return await (db.select(table)..where((tbl) => tbl.id.equals(id))).getSingle();
}
```

If I remove ..where and add ..limit(1) the query runs fine:

```
Future<dynamic> getById(int id) async {
  return await (db.select(table)..limit(1)).getSingle();
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems that flutter can't infer the types, so I made the query with the requested ones:

```
Future<dynamic> getById(int id) async {
  return await (db.select(table)..where((HasResultSet tbl) => table.id.equals(id) as Expression<bool>)).getSingle();
}
```

And now it's working fine.